# Angular JS on Rails - Argument 'RaffleCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm following a tutorial for integer Angular JS on a RoR project.

In my controller js files i've got this:

**raffle.coffee**

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

@RaffleCtrl = ($scope) ->
    $scope.entries = [  

        {name:"name1"}
        {name:"name2"}
        {name:"name3"}
        {name:"name4"}
    ]
```

and in my controller html (generated by rails) i've got this:

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Raffle</h1>

<div ng-controller="RaffleCtrl">
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newEntry.name">
    </form>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
            {{entry.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

so it should repeat the four name in the array entries but it doesn't work: i open the log and i found this error:

> Argument 'RaffleCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define the [ng-app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive in `application.html.erb`:

```
<html ng-app="Raffler">
...
</html>
```

Then in `raffle.js.coffee` replace this:

```
@RaffleCtrl = ($scope) ->
```

With this:

```
angular.module('Raffler', []).controller "RaffleCtrl", ($scope) ->
```

You must set the required `ng-app` directive in your Angular apps--this specifies the element as the *root element*. Do this in your application layout, on a high-level/root element like a *body* or *html* tag. Important note, you can designate this directive *once and only once*--if you mistakenly add multiple then the first designation in the app will be used to define the root element.

After you add *ng-app*, then specify a matching *root module* using the name you specified in `ng-app`. Leaving the array empty in the definition indicates that you're defining the module rather than invoking it. It doesn't matter what name you use, just make sure it's something relatively descriptive of your app, unique among your modules and that you specify precisely the same name for your root module that you added in `ng-app. This module will either contain your application code directly, or will have dependencies on other modules that contain it.

Basically, you must give your application an `ng-app` attribute, designating the doc's root element. And then you must create your Angular root module using that same name--"Raffler" in this case.

This should be relevant regardless but FWIW I was using *Rails '4.1.5'* and the *angularjs-rails gem 1.4.4.*