# Angular/Rails/CoffeeScript: "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'RaffleCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm currently doing the RailsCast Angular on Rails tutorial, but my code isn't working and the similar solutions I've found on stack overflow haven't helped. I'm getting the following error when I load my page:

```
"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'RaffleCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<h1 class="center">Raffler- Select a winner for the scholarship!</h1>

<div ng-controller="RaffleCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="addEntry()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newEntry.name">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
            {{entry.name}}
            <span ng-show="entry.winner" ng-class="{highlight: entry == lastWinner}" class="winner">WINNER</SPAN>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <button ng-click="drawWinner()">Choose Winner </button>
</div>
```

Here's my application.html.erb file with the ng-app line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
```

My CoffeScript:

```
@RaffleCtrl = ($scope) ->
    $scope.entries = [
        {name: "Anthony"}
        {name: "Jimmy"}
        {name: "Timothy"}
    ]

    $scope.addEntry = ->
        $scope.entries.push($scope.newEntry)
        $scope.newEntry = {}

    $scope.drawWinner = ->
        pool = []
        angular.forEach $scope.entries, (entry) ->
            pool.push(entry) if !entry.winner
        if pool.length > 0
            entry = pool[Math.floor(Math.random()*pool.length)]
            entry.winner = true
            $scope.lastWinner = entry
```

Comment: Why `@RaffleCtrl`? What is `this` here?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, one moment I'm answering my own question.

Comment: Silly me, I found the exact answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424459/angular-js-on-rails-argument-rafflectrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefined).